# Laravel : display related json file in vliew

Tags: php, json, laravel, relationship

I want to display related json file or url in view include table

i tried to combine between DB and json file but no result

i can only get json url and display him in view :

view

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="laravel_crud">
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>code</th>
       <th>abreviation</th>
       <th>statut</th>

    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach($content as $course)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $course['code'] }}</td>
       <td>{{ $course['abreviation'] }}</td>
       <td>{{ $course['statut'] }}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

All that's test

What i want to do is :

i have 5 json links : notes students status faculties subjets

Relationships i want to use for Json files :

- students hasmany notes
- notes hasmany subjets
- notes hasone status
- notes hasone faculties

file's json content :

- notes = id , student_id , note, status_id
- subjets = id , subjets
- faculties = id , name
- status = id , name
- student = id , name . lastname , faculty_id

i don't know how to include the json's links and relate between them after display them in table in view

Comment: Post your controller and models. Are you trying to output data from DB in JSON form to your view? I dont get what role are the  JSON files playing here.

Comment: json is source of data